# check count datatable is empty or not

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have trouble to get count datatables, i need to chect that table is emtpy or not, this my code :

```
var table = $("#tbl_tmppo");
        var target = table.attr('data-table');

        var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        } ).DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "ajax": host+'datatable/'+target,
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ -1 ],
                "className": "dt-body-left",
            }]
        });
```

i'm kinda stuck in here, i wanna check if i dont have data on Otable, i need do something, if not i need to something else. Anyone can help me??

Update :
I was using  like oTable.Data().length, but it always show 0 length to me even i have 2 record on that table. if i use oTable.Data().count() is show error not undifined.

CLOSED. Tq for kcp code

```
oTable.on('draw', function () {
    /* Now you can count rows */
    var count = table.data().count()-1;
```

});

so i can get count my data. Tq kcp!!! U're awsome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataFilter` to get length of rows.

```
DataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    ajax: {
        url: host+'datatable/'+target,
        dataFilter: function(data){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
            /* Here you have your results */
            json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
            json.data = json.list;

            return data;
        }
    }
    "columnDefs": [{
       "targets": [ -1 ],
       "className": "dt-body-left",
     }]
})
```

@edit:
For non-backend data you can use `draw` event.
For example:

```
oTable.on('draw', function () {
    /* Now you can count rows */
    var count = table.find("tr").size();
});
```

@edit2: You can also use `data().count()` method of `DataTable.API`

```
oTable.on('draw', function () {
        /* Now you can count rows */
        var count = table.data().count();
});
```

Comment: ok i'm gonna try that. Hope work, i will give u information if is work or not. :)

Comment: well, honestly i've not yet response from backend, cause i dont know how to callback totalrecords on table. and sorry for my languange

Comment: Oh.. I was thinking you using backend. Let me a moment for edit an answer.

Comment: Dude!! Tq very much is wrok, well kinda work, i just use var count = table.find("tr").size() -1; to get my row data. tq verymuch dude!!!! i will make approved u code. Tq again :D

Answer (score -1):

```
function CountRows() {
    var totalRowCount = 0;
    var rowCount = 0;
    var table = document.getElementById("tblCustomers");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        totalRowCount++;
        if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
    var message = "Total Row Count: " + totalRowCount;
    message += "\nRow Count: " + rowCount;
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: can u make format codes like my code?? Casue is kinda diferent for me